# Does comet server data in the iframe just accumulate?

Tags: node.js, comet, long-polling, server-push

I push [script]dosomething()[/script] tags into the iframe for my comet server using chunked data, but script tags just continues to accumulate forever. How do I wipe it after every script tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Wipe script tag

**P.S: When you want to wipe script tags it is probably to follow [Does comet server data in the iframe just accumulate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637987/does-comet-server-data-in-the-iframe-just-accumulate/6646048#6646048)**

I believe you should [close the connection after sometime](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming#How_will_you_decide_when_to_close_the_connection.3F)(**no good, see [Does comet server data in the iframe just accumulate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637987/does-comet-server-data-in-the-iframe-just-accumulate/6646048#6646048) instead**) which automatically frees up the memory associated with that request. You then off course need to reconnect. [This page](http://ajaxpatterns.org/HTTP_Streaming) says something else even:

> "Page Streaming" means the browser
>   discovers server changes almost
>   immediately. This opens up the
>   possibility of real-time updates in
>   the browser, and allows for
>   bi-directional information flow.
>   However, it's quite a departure from
>   standard HTTP usage, which leads to
>   several problems. First, there are
>   unfortunate memory implications,
>   because the Javascript keep
>   accumulating, and the browser must
>   retain all of that in its page model.
>   In a rich application with lots of
>   updates, that model is going to grow
>   quickly, and at some point a page
>   refresh will be necessary in order to
>   avoid hard drive swapping, or a worse
>   fate.

This advices to reload the page which is also an option. But I think closing that connection(iframe) and reconnecting might also work.

Comet has a lot of problems you need to hack around:

- As you can read from [this WIKI page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29#Hidden_iframe) it also has problems with "reliable error handling method, and the impossibility of tracking the state of the request calling process.".
- Also Internet Explorer needs to sent some junk to get the process started(see http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/05/the-forever-frame-technique/)

That's why I again recommend you to use socket.io(see below) which takes care of all this nonsense.

## Socket.io

I advice you to use [socket.io](http://socket.io) instead, which is very good product. It is [supported by all major browsers](http://socket.io/#browser-support). As you can see it support a lot of transport(XHR, Websockets, etc) and choices the best one available on your browser for the best performance.

Comment: When you want to wipe script tags it is probably to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637987/does-comet-server-data-in-the-iframe-just-accumulate/6646048#6646048

Answer (score 2):

## Wipe script tag without reconneting

You can remove script tag every time that it is executed by adding some code when the server prints chunk.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Calls your message handler
app.handle("Hello World");

// Removes this script element
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
    elem = scripts[scripts.length - 1];

elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
</script>
```

Compressed version

```
<script type="text/javascript">
app.handle("Hello World");
(function(){var a=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),a=a[a.length-1];a.parentNode.removeChild(a)})();
</script>
```

But, Hidden Iframe or Forever Iframe is too annoying to use as Alfred mentioned. Personally, I think this classical way makes Comet look graceless and charmless.

## jQuery Stream

My recommendation is to use [jQuery Stream](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-stream/), which provides the unified two-way communication interface over WebSocket and HTTP protocol. It is a light-weight client-side JavaScript Library such as jQuery.

The enhanced Iframe transport being used by jQuery Stream is different from the classical one in many ways, requries text/plain response containing only messages instead of text/html response and empties the response every time that it's handled.

According to some user's [test](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-stream/issues/detail?id=16#c2), Internet Explorer 8 using enhanced Iframe transport has no problem with messages of several megabytes (unlike Firefox using XMLHttpRequest as transport, which is really struggling).

Comment: This is much better than reconnecting. But using socket.io is even better if you ask me.

Comment: thank you very much, jquery stream looks like it will really help